# JQuery validationEngine not working on firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validation-engine

I'm trying to get a form validated with the jQuery validation engine plugin and it is not working on latest firefox  or IE.

This is my  on the form page:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js" type ="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
     jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
        jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();
    });

            function checkHELLO(field, rules, i, options){
        if (field.val() != "HELLO") {
            // this allows to use i18 for the error msgs
            return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
        }
    }
  </script>
```

And here are some of the form fields for reference:

```
<form action ="enviar.jsp" method="post" name="seguimiento" id="seguimiento">
<label>GolTV:</label>
<input name="Gol" type="number" id="Gol" title="Gol" min="0" class="validate[custom[number],min(0)]">
<br>
<label>Bajas:</label>
<input name="Bajas" type="number" id="Bajas" title="Bajas" min="0" class="validate[custom[number],min(0)]">
<br>
<label>Preinst teléfono:</label>
<input name="Preinstalaciones" type="number" id="Preinstalaciones" title="Preinstalaciones" min="0" class="validate[custom[number],min(0)]">
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
```

This works just fine on Chrome, if someone inputs a negative number or a letter in the fields a message pops and says that's wrong, however nothing is happening on firefox.

JavaScript console just complains about this:

```
Fecha y hora: 27/03/2013 16:45:11
Advertencia: Error al interpretar el valor para 'filter'.  Declaración rechazada.
Archivo de origen: http://<myhost>/Tecnicos/css/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css
```

Which translates into Error interpreting the value for 'filter'. Declaration rejected.

There are a few of these, but all related to the css, nothing with javascript at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: That filter error is a CSS warning, it even mentions the CSS file. It's not a JavaScript error. Your error must be elsewhere.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I guess so but the console doesn't say anything else, Firebug doesn't show anything else either. And what's most disturbing is that it works fully on Chrome. Any idea??

Comment: You'll need to do better than "it doesn't work".

Comment: @FritsvanCampen basically the form gets submitted no matter what is on the fields.
If I write -1 on any of the numeric fields that require min 0 the form gets submitted. Same happens when writing words.

Comment: Imagine you're a car mechanic and you're talking to another car mechanic about a car. And you say: "When I turn the key the engine doesn't start". What do you think the other mechanic will say/do? Do that.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen the mechanic will ask me how am I turning the key and what key I'm using. I think such information was provided on the original question. If not please be more specific on what do you need so you can help me out.

Comment: No, the mechanic will look at the engine to see why the key signal isn't starting it. Look at the engine, that's what mechanics do.

Comment: Well that's not helping me at all to be honest. If I'm here asking the question is because I don't know what else to do. So asking me to check the engine doesn't work

Comment: @FritsvanCampen sorry but do you have any more specific tips that can help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Get to debugging. Is the validation not being called? Is the script not loading? Is there an Error somewhere? .. etc.

Comment: If you read the question you'll find I already did that before coming here. Anyway this problem is solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the localization rules weren't added.

After adding

```
  <script src="js/jquery.validationEngine-es.js"></script>
```

It works.

Comment: Also did what TheSnooker suggests on his answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery("#formID").validationEngine();
```

shouldn't that be

```
jQuery("#seguimiento").validationEngine();
```